# When the selection depends on a prior experience, what statistical test is appropriate?

Tags: probability, computational-statistics

We have raised a batch of frogs on one species A fly. We then present the frogs with species A and a second species B fly. Will the frogs pick species A or B? Lets say 40% choose A and 60% choose B. is this selection random? If not random, then how do you show that it depends on prior food exposure? or it does not depend on prior food exposure? or that one fly species is preferred over another? So, we know that the frogs were raised on species A flies. The question is when a frog raised on species A flies is presented with A flies and B flies. When it makes the choice is it a random or not random choice? So, if 50% choose A and 50% choose B. Then can one say it is random selection? But if 60% choose A and 40% choose B, can we say that it is not random? Can you further state that the choice was influenced by prior exposure?

When the selection might depend on a prior experience, what statistical test is appropriate? Is it possible to set this up as a chi square test? or McNemar's? How do you set it up?

Comment: checked cross-validated and could not find anything that responds to this question.

Answer (score 1):

> But if 60% choose A and 40% choose B, can we say that it is not random?

That depends on the sample size. We can compute the probability that a result *at least as extreme as this* would occur if the null hypothesis (of no preference, that the choices are at random) were true. If that probability is sufficiently low, we conclude that the explanation for what we see isn't just that of chance.

> Can you further state that the choice was influenced by prior exposure?

Yes, if your experiment controls for, or randomizes out the alternatives.

e.g. if they could have an underlying preference for A even if not exposed, you would need a control group. If they could have a preference based on which fly was on the left hand side (say), you could randomize that, or design your experiment to measure or eliminate the effect.

Random selection on anything you don't control or at least measure becomes your tool for dealing with all the variables you didn't think of.

Answer (score 0):

You should have raised two batches of *randomly allocated* frogs, one fed only with flies "A" and the other fed with "regular" flies. Then you'd have a control group and a treatment group to compare.

In your situation, suppose 100% of the frogs have chosen flies "A" after exposure. How would you tell whether they did that *because* of the previous exposure, or simply because flies "A" taste better (yuck!)? The point is, without a control group, you can't tell if the frog gastronomy is influenced or not by previous exposure.

Another hypothetical situation to exemplify is this: suppose someone else did raise a similar batch of frogs and found out that all these frogs choose flies "A" as soon as this options shows up in their menu. Is this scenario, previous exposure has in fact a negative effect on flies "A" as frog snacks.

Google "control group", "treatment group", "counterfactual analysis", "impact evaluation" to get you started.

Comment: ok. let me clarify. for point of simplifying the project, i left out a few things. We also have a batch of frogs that were raised on Fly B.  In the real case, the frog was exposed to four foods: a fly they are known not to eat, a fly that has is very bitter, and fly A and fly B which taste the same, except one is smaller than the other. Does that help guide your recommendation? Would you use a McNemar's test? How would you set it up?

Comment: Were the frogs *randomly* assigned to batches A and B? If not, there may be some selection bias in the groups. What do you mean when you say "in the real case, the frog was exposed to four foods"? There were 4 groups? Or the second group had all these foods? Finally, if you have the number of frogs eating fly A and the total number of frogs (in each batch) there is no need to use McNemar's test, you can use Fisher's Exact Test.

Comment: Well, no the frogs were brought from different locations where they were used to eating a specific type of fly.

Comment: In the actual experiment, each frog was exposed to 4 items on the menu. Yes, there were 4 different food groups for each frog whether raised on A or B flies. Ok. so, how would you set up the 2x2 . would it be:

Comment: c1. frogs on diet a; c2 frogs on diet b; d1 outcome frog on diet a selects diet a; d2 fron on diet a selects diet b; d3 frog on diet a selects item c; d4 frog on diet a selects item d. don't know how to type the matrix in this box.

Comment: Considering that the batches are not random, whatever test you perform on the outcomes will only tell if the difference between batches is statistically significant or not, but you won't be able to tell whether this is due to previous exposure to a specific diet or due to any other characteristic that is not equally distributed among batches - and this can be anything, from tongue length to temperature during first weeks of life... If you want to proceed anyway, google "Fisher's Exact Test".

Answer (score -1):

I'd say there's not enough information to determine entropy. I'd also say that conditional probability is the only facet of probability that could legitimately be applied here.

Comment: would you calculate the probabilities and then use these expected probabilities in McNemar's test? How would you calculate the probability of frog conditioned on fly A to select fly A and probability of frog to select fly B?